# How to change InfiniteScrollAdapter animation image

Tags: java, infinite-scroll, codenameone

The default image for InfiniteProgress is an ugly looking icon from Google material. I have a collection of some fonticons and I will like to set the InfiniteScrollAdapter's animation image to one of them in code.

I know how to do this with static image and a theme constant but I want it done in code. I tried below in my init method which works fine, but there are cases where I want a particular InfiniteProgress to have a different icon and that isn't possible anymore:

```
UIManager.getInstance().setLookAndFeel(new DefaultLookAndFeel(UIManager.getInstance()) {
    @Override
    public void bind(Component cmp) {
        if (cmp instanceof InfiniteProgress) {
            ((InfiniteProgress) cmp).setAnimation(fontIcon("\ue834", 4, 0xed1d3b));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the theme constant `infiniteImage` but that might be too wide of a change for your taste.

We'll add a new API in the upcoming update both to `InfiniteScrollAdapter` and to `InfiniteContainer`. Called:

```
public InfiniteProgress getInfiniteProgress()
```

This will allows you to customize the infinite image directly on the progress component that underlies the scroll adapter.